# How do I connect to NAMED INSTANCE of SqlServer 2008 running on custom port from another network?

Tags: networking, sql-server-2008, router, ssms

I have a named instance of MS SQL Server 2008 running on port 1456. TCP/IP and NamedPipes are ENABLED for the server. No Aliases created.

**local address:** 192.168.1.123\RM - works from local computer and local subnet (no ports specified when connecting)
**local name:** my-server\RM - works from local computer and local subnet (no ports specified when connecting)
**remote address (thru the router):** 209.111.111.111,1456\RM - DOES NOT WORK from local or remote networks. I get "login failed" error, all because I hit the DEFAULT instance all the time, which is SQL 2005 (works fine).

Port forwarding on the router is setup. Port 1456 is open.

#### How do I connect to the server from ANOTHER NETWORK (going thru the router)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User a tcp/ip connection directly to the port:  209.111.111.111,1456

If you specify the port, do not put \RM at the end.

Comment: it takes me to the DEFAULT INSTANCE that's running on 1434

Comment: Are your instances set up to use static tcp/ip ports instead of dynamic ones?  Are you sure the routers are forwarding the correct source port to the correct destination port?

Comment: thank you ... the router port forward was forwarding to the wrong port